# Does php urlencode the same with java urlencode?

Tags: java, php, urlencode, encode

In PHP：

```
php -r "echo urlencode('["IM"]'); "
```

The result is `%5BIM%5D`

But in java

```
String text = URLEncoder.encode('["IM"]',"UTF-8");
System.out.println("text" + text);
```

The result is `text%5B%22IM%22%5D`

What's the different between these two functions? How can I implement a java code to complete the same function of php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
php -r "echo urlencode('["IM"]'); "
```

The result is %5BIM%5D because the function urlencode is actually only taking the string `[IM]` as its input. while in java

```
String text = URLEncoder.encode('["IM"]',"UTF-8");
```

The string being passed is actually: `["IM"]` which generates the value `%22` which is encode-string for `"` the quote mark.

Answer (score 3):

```
String text = URLEncoder.encode('[IM]',"UTF-8");
System.out.println("text" + text);
```

gives `%5BIM%5D`

```
echo urlencode('["IM"]');
```

gives `%5B%22IM%22%5D`

```
echo urlencode('[IM]');
```

gives `%5BIM%5D`

```
echo urlencode('[\"IM\"]');
```

gives `%5B%5C%22IM%5C%22%5D`

Comment: Because in fact I want to encode a JSONArray.tostring(). So the origin string maybe like ['IM','game'].Can not simple delete the '

Comment: Which is it that you actually want? `%5B%22IM%22%5D`, `%5BIM%5D`, or `%5B%5C%22IM%5C%22%5D`? The `[` escapes to `%5B`, the `]` escapes to `%5D` and `"` escapes to `%22`.

Comment: If what you want is `["IM"]` then your original java code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

try to escape internal qoutes

```
php -r "echo urlencode('[\"IM\"]'); "
```

Comment: It's the same.But I want a java code. The php is write by someone else.